# Как объединить графику с двух bitmap'ов и найти пересечение по цветам?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    bmpPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
}
image = Image.FromFile(bmpPath);
image = Image.FromFile(bmpPath);
int width = image.Width;
int height = image.Height;
pictureBox1.Width = width;
pictureBox1.Height = height;
bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
bitmap1 = new Bitmap(image);
graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
graphics1 = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
graphics1.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
```

Здравствуйте, суть в том что мне нужно загрузить цифру bmp и нарисовать линию, сама цифра черного цвета а линия красная. 
Как мне сделать проверку пересечений по цвету допустим когда красная линия пересекает где-то цифру.
Вот тут тщетные попытки

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color color1 = Color.Red;
    int[,] pixels = new int[pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height];
    for (int i = 0; i < pictureBox1.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pictureBox1.Height; j++)
        {
            Color color  = bitmap1.GetPixel(i,j);
            if(bitmap1.GetPixel(i,j) == Color.Red)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что ради интереса я создавал массив цвета, и брал каждый цвет пикселя с обоих битмапов. В одном битмапе были только черного цвета пикселя, а в другом только белого.

Comment: Никогда не используйте `CreateGraphics()`! В приличном обществе за это ногами бьют... / Вам нужно рисовать на битмапе: `Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1)`

Answer (score 0):

Просто сравниваете цвета пикселов с одинаковыми координатами на обоих изображениях:

```
for (int y = 0; y < bitmap1.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap1.Width; x++)
    {
        if (bitmap1.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb() == Color.Red.ToArgb() &&
            bitmap2.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

И обратите внимание на порядок обхода битмапов (матриц, двумерных массивов): из-за кэширования данных линиями в процессорном кэше этот способ быстрее.

Однако, метод `GetPixel` настолько медленный (как и `SetPixel`), что в любом случае код с его применением неэффективен. Для обработки больших изображений используйте [LockBits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Он что то не может определить в первом битмапе красный цвет, может я не правильно отрисовываю?

Comment: @Oleg_Ba - вы на графиксе пикчабокса отрисовываете, а не на битмапе.